# JSInterop is not add the script before OnAfterRenderAsync

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a component for Blazor. I have a `JSInterop` that is defined like that

```
public class JSMarkdownInterop
{
    IJSRuntime jsRuntime;

    public JSMarkdownInterop(IJSRuntime JSRuntime)
    {
        jsRuntime = JSRuntime;

        jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",
            "/_content/PSC.Blazor.Components.MarkdownEditor/js/markdownEditor.js");
    }

    public async ValueTask AddJS(string targetUrl)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("loadJs", targetUrl);
    }
}
```

The function `loadJS` is in the `markdownEditor.js`. So, in the component I added this code in the `OnInitialized` function

```
protected JSMarkdownInterop JSModule { get; private set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    if (JSModule == null)
        JSModule = new JSMarkdownInterop(JSRuntime);

    base.OnInitialized();
}
```

then, in the `OnAfterRenderAsync` I want to call the `AddJS` function to add some scripts.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);

    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSModule.AddJS(easyMDEJS);
    }
}
```

I end up to have an error because apparently the fucntion `loadJS` was undefined.

[image]

How you can see in the above screenshot, there is the error but also the application added the script. Then, I think the application adds the script after the first render.

How can I delay the first render until the script is added? Or how can I add the script on time for the first render?

## Update

I changed the `JSMarkdownInterop` like that

```
public class JSMarkdownInterop : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask;

    public JSMarkdownInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",
            "./_content/PSC.Blazor.Components.MarkdownEditor/js/markdownEditor.js")
            .AsTask());
    }

    public async ValueTask AddJS(string targetUrl)
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("loadJs", targetUrl);
    }
}
```

but I receive the same error.

Comment: Why do you load the module it with a fire-and-forget method call? You should be awaiting that call, storing the returned IJSObjectReference and using that to invoke methods later. See the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules

Comment: The function is not exported in the module. Read the docs on ES6 modules.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your JSModule in OnAfterRender, like this

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{    
    if (firstRender)
    {
        if (JSModule == null)
             JSModule = new JSMarkdownInterop(JSRuntime);

        await JSModule.AddJS(easyMDEJS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Unfortunately, it is not working

Comment: Try to apply the solution of @Surinder Singh but add up `await JSModule.AddJS(easyMDEJS);` this `Task.Delay(500)`